# JAVA: Calculating the power of all numbers between 0 and 100 with IntStream

Tags: java, java-stream

I need to calculate the power of all numbers between 0 and 100 and then print them  using IntStream.
This is what I got, but it doesn't work. I understand why it doesn't work, but i can't find a solution.

```
IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i * i + 1).limit(100).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: What output do you want? What do you mean by "power of all numbers between 0 and 100"?

Comment: *"It does not work"* - in what way does it not work? You are missing the "power"ing, take a look at the map-functionality of streams.

Comment: Blatantly looking at the code, `i * i` does look like powering. @luk2302

Comment: the output should be as follows:
0
1
4
9
16
25
36
all the way to 9801 (99*99)

Comment: @devRicher that is correct - but `i * i + 1` is not "correct" powering ^^

Comment: Not exactly knowing what streams are, but, shouldn't it be `i -> i = i * i`? @luk2302

Comment: @devRicher no, what the code does it starts at 0, then apply the function `i -> i * i + `, resulting in 0 * 0 + 1 = 1, then it applies the function again 1 * 1 + 1 = 2, then again 2 * 2 + 1 = 5, then again 5 * 5 + 1 = 26, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Since your question is not clear, I am making a couple assumptions.

> I need to calculate the power of all numbers between 0 and 100

Based on your example code, I'm assuming what you mean is that you want to calculate the *square* of each number between 0 and 100.

I am assuming you want an output which looks something like...

> 0
>
> 1
>
> 4
>
> 9
>
> 16
>
> ...
>
> 10000

If so, then I suggest two things. First, replace your `iterate` with `range`. Second, use `map` to map the values to their squares.

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0,100).map(x -> x * x).forEach(System.out::println);
```

What we are doing:

For each integer x ∈ [0,100]: print x*x.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation, this is what i was looking for!
Apparently i made a little translation error with square and power (not native english)

Comment: @HGLouis - Glad to help.

Comment: @CoryOwens Glad I could help! I added in the "16" one to hit the changed character minimum.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments above I do not know exacting what powers you are looking for and what does not work but here is one way using IntStream to get the power of all the numbers using the (i*i+1) approach you using:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(0, 100).map(i -> i * i + 1);
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you, this helps indeed :)

Answer (score 0):

If you must use IntStream.iterate, you can try something like `IntStream.iterate(1, i -> (int)Math.pow(Math.sqrt(i)+1, 2)).limit(100).forEach(System.out::println);`. Not efficient but meets your needs. If you want an elegant solution instead, try the other answers.